# providing input to shell from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

First of all, I'm very new to programming in general and Python in particular, I've been studying it for about 1.5 weeks, so any detailed criticism and/or explained corrections are welcome.

We are producing a certain device at my company and it is being tested at the QA station by using a shell script that is provided by the developer. I'm not allowed to change the said script.

At a certain point of the test, a comparison between two images is needed, it is done by showing the pictures to the operator of the station and asking for his/her input in y/n format.

I'm trying to come up with a python script that would be able to provide this input automatically based on the score that I got from the image comparison.

I have 2 problems, first being that I can't seem to catch the moment of the script reading the input, only an echo before or after.
Second is that I can't seem to find a way to provide the input and let the script continue to do it's thing.

Now onto the tech details: I'm using this module to handle the image comparison.

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
import cv2 as cv2

class Compare_images:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = None
        self.original = cv2.imread("img1.png")
        self.contrast = cv2.imread("img2.png")

    def compare_images(self):
        self.s = ssim(self.original, self.contrast, multichannel = True)
        return self.s
```

This is the example of the shell script

```
echo "Welcome!"

#something happens here

read -p "Script is asking for user input as in y/n:" userinput

if [ "$userinput" = "n" ]
then 
    #script continues 1 way
else 
    #script continues another way
fi
```

And this is my main script.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from compare_images import Compare_images
reply = None

def run(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for path in run("./shellscript.sh"):
        if 'Script is asking for user input as in y/n:' in path.decode():
            a = Compare_images()
            a.compare_images()
            result = a.s
            if result<0.9:
                reply = "n"
                #input to shell script is given
                print(f'comparison result is {result}')

            else:
                reply = "y"
                #input to shell script is given
                print(f'comparison result is {result}')
```

I'm using python 3.6 and running on ubuntu 18.04. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send data to the external process you need to add an `stdin = PIPE` argument to the `Popen` call. Then use write and flush to send the data to the process (`flush` is required since the stream is buffered).

```
process.stdin.write('yes\n')
process.stdin.flush()
```

Also pass `text=True` to the `Popen` call to let Python handle binary/text decoding for you. Then you no longer need to call `decode()` yourself.

The more difficult part here is that the `read -p "prompt" var` does not print a newline after the prompt. So your `readline` is stuck waiting for a complete line. You probably need to use `read` here to read a few characters at a time and compare to what you expect...

You may want to explore the [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module as a simpler alternative.